# How to remove extra spaces in od output when reading from /dev/random

Tags: bash, random

I'm making a script to auto-generate a url with a random number at a specific location. This will be for calling a JSON API for a random endpoint. The end goal is to generate something like this:

`curl -s http://api.openbeerdatabase.com/v1/beers/<RAND_INT>.json | jq '.'`

where `<RAND_INT>` is a randomly-generated number. I can create this random number with the following command:

```
$ od -An -N2 -i /dev/random
          126
```

I do not know why the 10 extra spaces are in the output. When I chain the above commands together to generate the URL, I get this:

```
$ echo http://api.openbeerdatabase.com/v1/beers/`od -An -N2 -i /dev/random`.json                                                                                   
http://api.openbeerdatabase.com/v1/beers/ 43250.json
```

As you see, there is a single extra space in the generated URL. How do I avoid this?

I've also tried subshelling the rand_int command `$(od -An -N2 -i /dev/random)` but that produces the same thing. I've thought about piping the commands together, but I don't know how to capture the output of the rand_int command in a variable to be used in the URL.

Comment: Pipe the output into `tr` or `sed` or something to delete the spaces.

Comment: Have you considered just using `$RANDOM`?

Comment: [What is the purpose of the random integer?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) Are you trying to do something security-related, such as generating a session ID or single-use URL?

Comment: Try this... `od -An -N2 -i /dev/random | tr -d ' \n'`

Comment: @l0b0 I'm just trying to get a random beer from the database. I think it'd be a cool script for my dotfiles =D

Comment: Have you considered using a URL like `http://api.openbeerdatabase.com/v1/beers/random.json` and returning a random entry in the back-end? Might be much simpler, since most databases support getting a random row.

Comment: @l0b0 I don't own the backend, tho it is an open source project and I might add that functionality (but honestly, there are other databases out there with more data, so I might just switch to a different api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments show, there's more than one way to do this. Here's what I would do:

```
(( n = $( od -An -N2 -i /dev/urandom ) ))
echo http://api.openbeerdatabase.com/v1/beers/${n}.json
```

Or, to put it in one line:

```
echo http://api.openbeerdatabase.com/v1/beers/$(( $( od -An -N2 -i /dev/urandom ) )).json
```

Or, just use `${RANDOM}` instead, since `bash` provides it, although its values top out at 32767, which might be one reason you preferred your `od`-based method.

Comment: Honestly I had no idea about `$RANDOM`. That should fulfill my purposes. Thanks!